# CountDownTimer is not cancelling

Tags: android, kotlin

None of the other instances of this question are solving my problem. I have a Fragment that appears at the end of a transaction sequence. It is meant to close the app when a `CountDownTimer` contained within it counts down:

```
class TerminalFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        startOverButton.setOnClickListener {

            returnToStart()
        }

        initUi()

        startCountDown()

    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        AppLog.i(TAG, "onStop()")

        stopCountdown()

    }
}

private fun startCountDown() {

    terminalCountdown = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {

            AppLog.i(TAG, "Terminal countdown finished")

            (context as MainActivity).finish()
        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

        }
    }
    .start()
}

private fun stopCountdown() {
    AppLog.i(TAG, "stopCountDown() - Terminal countdown stopped")

    terminalCountdown?.cancel()

    terminalCountdown = null

}

private fun returnToStart() {

    AppLog.i(TAG, "returnToStart()")

    stopCountdown()

    (context as MainActivity).restartFlow()
}
```

`stopCountDown()` is being called whenever the fragment is navigated away from, but it somehow survives sometimes and closes the app from another Fragment. Using logs, I've also discovered that there appears to be 2 instances of this countdown sometimes. How do I insure that this countdown is never active outside of this fragment?

Comment: *"2 instances of this countdown sometimes"* -> if in any case your `startCountDown()` is called multiple times, the former timer reference will be lost and it will keep running

Comment: Code looks good; you appear to be handling the lifecycle correctly. `onStop()` is always called 1-for-1 with `onStart()`, unless you're doing something really crazy... It is likely the problem lies in code not posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Shrey Greg mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565290/countdowntimer-is-not-cancelling/58700399#comment103455402_58565290), I was creating a new instance of `CountdownTimer` every time I wanted to restart it. This lost the reference to the previous instance, making it impossible to cancel.